# TypeError: b is undefined jquery.min.js:3:6371

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar uma função que dada o tipo de postagem retorne os achados que estiverem no banco de dados usando `jQuery-min-3.1.1.js`, PHP e JSON para troca de informações. Porém recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro: `TypeError: b is undefined jquery.min.js:3:6371` Eu não declarei essa var no meu script, e não to entendendo o por que desse erro.

jquery/javascript:

```
function loadPost() {
    var size = arrayPost.length;
    var imgPath = '/images/upload/poster/';
    var post = arrayPost;
    for (i = 0; i < post.rows; i++) {
        $('.side-left').append(htmlPost);
        $($('.cont-desc')[i]).attr('title', post.description[i]);
        $($('.cont-type')[i]).html(post.type[i]);
        $($('.cont-url')[i]).attr('href', post.url[i]);
        $($('.cont-url-img')[i]).attr('src', imgPath + post.poster[i]);
        $($('.cont-demo')[i]).html(post.title[i]);
    }
}
//navbar---------------------------------
var bcd = 0;
var ecd = 12;
function mountNewPubli(d) {
    $('.side-left').html('');
    arrayPost = d;
    loadPost();
    $('.side-left').append('<button class="btnloadmore" type="button">Carregar +</button>');
}
$('.search-label').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var label = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/sys/etc/search-label.php',
        data: {type: label, b: bcd, e: ecd}
    }).done(function (d) {
        console.debug(d)
        if (d.status == 404) {
            callError(404, 'Não foi possível obter ' + $(this).html() + '{search-label: return 404}');
        } else if (d.status == 200) {
            bcd = (ecd + 1);
            ecd += 12;
            mountNewPubli();
        } else {
            console.debug(d);
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        callError(404, 'Não foi possível obter ' + $(this).html() + ' {Path_not_found}');
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sys/lib.php';

if (isAjax()) {
    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sys/class/class-posts.php';
        $post = new Publication();
        $return = $post->searchLabel($_GET['type'], (int) $_GET['b'], (int) $_GET['e']);
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente ele está acusando erro dentro do arquivo do jQuery. Tem certeza que fechou todas as tags HTML corretamente? Se possível, poste o código aqui.

Comment: Sim estão todas fechadas.

Comment: Posta o resto do código, talvez não esteja aí o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, primeiro a função `loadPost`:

```
function loadPost() {

    var size = arrayPost.length;
    var imgPath = '/images/upload/poster/';
    var post = arrayPost;

    ...

}
```

Aqui você recupera o valor de `arrayPost`, tanto para atribuir o valor de `size` quanto para `post`, porém a variável `arrayPost` não é definida neste escopo, apenas dentro da função `mountNewPubli`, onde a função `loadPost` é chamada. Tente, então, passar o valor desta variável por parâmetro:

```
function loadPost(arrayPost) {

    var size = arrayPost.length;
    var imgPath = '/images/upload/poster/';
    var post = arrayPost;

    ...

}
```

Agora a função `mountNewPubli`. Nela, só precisamos passar o parâmetro que acabamos de definir:

```
var bcd = 0;
var ecd = 12;

function mountNewPubli(d) {

    $('.side-left').html('');
    arrayPost = d;
    loadPost(arrayPost);

    ...

}
```

Porém, devemos lembrar que a função `mountNewPubli` possui um parâmetro `d`, que não tem seu valor passado durante a chamada, no *callback*  da requisição AJAX.

```
$('.search-label').click(function (ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var label = $(this).attr('data-type');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/sys/etc/search-label.php',
        data: {type: label, b: bcd, e: ecd}
    }).done(function (d) {

        console.debug(d)

        if (d.status == 404) {
            ...
        } else if (d.status == 200) {

            bcd = (ecd + 1);
            ecd += 12;
            mountNewPubli(); // <---- AQUI

        } else {
            console.debug(d);
        }

    }).fail(function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Considerando que este `d` seja o mesmo da função *callback*, passamos seu valor para a função `mountNewPubli`:

```
$('.search-label').click(function (ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var label = $(this).attr('data-type');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/sys/etc/search-label.php',
        data: {type: label, b: bcd, e: ecd}
    }).done(function (d) {

        console.debug(d)

        if (d.status == 404) {
            ...
        } else if (d.status == 200) {

            bcd = (ecd + 1);
            ecd += 12;
            mountNewPubli(d); // <---- AQUI

        } else {
            console.debug(d);
        }

    }).fail(function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

> Acredito que a utilização das variáveis `bcd` e `ecd` esteja ok, visto que as mesmas parecem estar definidas no escopo global do programa.

**Adendo #1**

Como observado pelo usuário [André Luis Marmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/66090/andr%c3%a9-luis-marmo), neste trecho de código, o índice `i` está na posição errada.

```
function loadPost() {
    var size = arrayPost.length;
    var imgPath = '/images/upload/poster/';
    var post = arrayPost;
    for (i = 0; i < post.rows; i++) {
        $('.side-left').append(htmlPost);
        $($('.cont-desc')[i]).attr('title', post.description[i]);
        $($('.cont-type')[i]).html(post.type[i]);
        $($('.cont-url')[i]).attr('href', post.url[i]);
        $($('.cont-url-img')[i]).attr('src', imgPath + post.poster[i]);
        $($('.cont-demo')[i]).html(post.title[i]);
    }
}
```

O correto seria:

```
function loadPost() {
    var size = arrayPost.length;
    var imgPath = '/images/upload/poster/';
    var post = arrayPost;
    for (i = 0; i < post.rows; i++) {
        $('.side-left').append(htmlPost);
        $($('.cont-desc')[i]).attr('title', post[i].description);
        $($('.cont-type')[i]).html(post[i].type);
        $($('.cont-url')[i]).attr('href', post[i].url);
        $($('.cont-url-img')[i]).attr('src', imgPath + post[i].poster);
        $($('.cont-demo')[i]).html(post[i].title);
    }
}
```

**Adendo #1.1**

Visto que, como esclarecido nos comentários, `post`, na função `loadPost`, não é uma lista de objetos, mas um objeto em que cada propriedade é uma lista, o adendo #1 pode ser ignorado para esta solução.

Comment: Caramba velho ajudou e muito!
A variável `arrayPost` está declarada sim, no começo do script. Não o postei por completo por que ta extenso então tentei por só as partes que são utilizadas nessa ação e acabei esquecendo da variável.
Depois que passei o resultado do ajax por parâmetro para `mountNewPubli()` como você disse, o algorítimo funcionou.

Comment: No loop do `loadPost()` o `[i]` passado no final do atributo do objeto funciona.
É que ao em vez de criar um objeto para cada publicação eu as coloco como array dentro dos atributos e então as chamo.

Comment: Faz sentido. Esse é o problema de não passar o código por completo. Deixa-o ambíguo. Inseri na resposta o adendo #1.1 esclarecendo esta parte.

Answer (score 0):

Você não possui uma variável "b", mas está passando um objeto que contém um atributo "b". Talvez possa ser alguma coisa com este objeto que está sendo passado.

```
data: {type: label, **b**: bcd, e: ecd}
```

Comment: Já alterei esse "b" mas continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Esse trecho "post.description[i]" está correto? Não seria post[i].description

Comment: @AndréLuisMarmo, bem observado. Adicionei à minha resposta um adendo citando sua correção.

Comment: Eu comentei na resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss o por que.